# Windows Batch : renaming files and replace it filename already exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename

I want to rename files in a directory using this command :

```
for /r %%x in (*.ath) do ren "%%x" *.txt
```

The problem is if the filename already exists, the file is not replaced.
Is there a simple way to delete the old file and then rename the new one ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @Ben's comment use

```
for /r %%x in (*.ath) do move "%%x" "%%~nx.txt" /y
```

Comment: Does not work, for /r %x in (*.ath) do move /Y "%x" *.txt ==> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"
With move /Y file.txt file.ath ==> this works
Seems that move does not accept * character

Comment: @Morti You're right, `move` doesn't support wildcards, I didn't know that. I have fixed my answer so it will work like the `*` does.